# Prove that $T$ is continuous.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am having a really hard time trying to solve this problem:

*Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed linear spaces and $T : X \to Y$ a linear operator with closed graph and finite-dimensional range $R(T)$. Prove that T is continuous.*

Obviously *the closed graph theorem* cannot be applied since our spaces are not neccessarily Banach ones. Nonetheless, at least "Y" is a Banach space because of its finite-dimensionality. I do not know how I can go further from here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It may be useful that it's enough to prove continuity in 0.

Comment: Assume first that $\dim R(T)=1$, i.e., $Tx = f(x)y$ with some linear functional $f : X\to\mathbb K$ and $y\in Y$.

Comment: I tried to combine both of your advices but still I cannot figure the details out...

Comment: Assume that there exists a bounded sequence $(x_n)$ for which $f(x_n)\to\infty$. Set $y_n := \frac{x_n}{f(x_n)}$. Then...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $T$ is not continuous at zero. Then there exist a sequence $(x_n)\subset X$ with $x_n\to 0$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that $\|Tx_n\|\ge\epsilon$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. Set $u_n := \frac{x_n}{\|Tx_n\|}\in X$. Then $u_n\to 0$ and $\|Tu_n\|=1$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$. Since $R(T)$ is finite-dimensional, there exists a subsequence $(u_n')$ of $(u_n)$ such that $(Tu_n')$ converges. Let $y\in Y$ be its limit. Then from $u_n'\to 0$ and $Tu_n'\to y$ we conclude that $y=0$. But $\|y\| = \lim_n\|Tu_n'\| = 1$. Contradiction!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Silly me. I ain't think to tackle it by contradiction.

Comment: Nonetheless, two questions: 

The finite-dimensionality of $R(T)$ implies that every bounded sequence, for instance $u_n$, to have a convergent subsequence??

Why $y = 0$?? how $u'_n \to 0$ and $Tu'_n \to y$ implies this ??

Comment: Yes, in a finite-dimensional space every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. And $y=0$ because of closed graph.

Comment: Wao, you are so great dude. Thank you so much. Everything is utterly clear now. But if you do not mind me asking, what I am doing wrong ?? How can I improve to get much much, really much, better at math ??

Comment: First you should check (and maybe upvote) my answer.

Comment: Done. I did check it. Next??

Comment: Thanks. Dude, to be good at math requires some talent and a lot of training. So, keep on doing exercises. It helps a lot. Good luck!